# How to stop iPhone from making a specific autocorrection?

Tags: ios, autocorrect

My iPhone *almost always* replaces the word *make* (lower-case) with the word *Male* (yes, with a capital M). I don't get auto-correct suggestion in a bubble. The change happens automatically immediately after I press the <kbd>Space</kbd> key after typing *make*.

I think this has been going on about 3-4 months. I’m wondering if I’m losing my mind. Almost every time I type the word *make* (including just there; I am typing this on my phone) it just magically changes to *Male*, and I have to select the word and manually retype it.

I‘ve checked in Settings app → General → Keyboard → Text Replacement, and there’s no such replacement defined.

So it seems my iPhone has just *learned* to do this, but I can’t think of any time I would have made this substitution myself.

**Question:** How can I fix this (without globally disabling auto-correction)?

**Bonus points for curiosity:** Why has my iPhone started doing this? I can’t see how it could learn to replace a very common word with a much less common word (with nonstandard capitalisation, at that). Seems like some kind of broken machine learning algorithm stuck in a weird self-affirming loop. But if so, why would this bug only manifest in a single persistent unwanted substitution? (My iPhone does seem to have reluctantly accepted that I rarely meant to type *ducking*, so clearly it can learn.)

Comment: What model of iPhone & version of iOS?

Answer (score 1):

If iOS is persistent in making this correction, make a text replacement:

https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/use-text-replacements-iph6d01d862/ios

Put the correct text as both the replacement and the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Open any app (Notes, Messages) with a text field and type the word *make* normally. Now when iPhone auto-correction subsystem offers a correction, simply tap on the `ｘ` button show besides the correction.

[image]

Now quit the app completely from multitasking UI and repeat this 4-5 times, until your iPhone stops suggesting the auto-correction to *Male*.

This way you have effectively made it learn that you do not want *make* to be changed to *Male*.

Comment: I should have mentioned: it does not show the autocorrect bubble. It just makes the substitution when I type the space after “make”.